# Share internet from a router ADSL to a cellular data phone ? is that possible

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet, proxy, cellular

is there a way to share my house wifi internet to my android phone using cellular data network
so when i am outside my house i can connect to internet
mybe a proxy or software need to be installed on both house PC and my phone
is it possible

Comment: Put a Wireless AP on the router near to the outside point and it should work fine. My AP is at the front and I get decent coverage in the front yard and the garage.

Answer (score 0):

No, using a cellular network won't work, since such networks operate in regulated frequency ranges.
Having said that, there are a number of optioms that you can use in the unlicensed frequency band (ie [ISM band](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISM_radio_band)). However, keep in mind that you won't achieve full mobility with that (e.g. just sitting into your car and being connected)

- If you just want internet access in the proximity of your house you can install an access point to the outside wall of your house.
- If you want internet access in a distant, but fixed location you can setup a point-to-point wireless link to there which usually involves the installation of two devices on the outside wall or roof. Assuming you have a clear line of sight to that site you can then setup a Wifi network in the remote site.

So as you can see, wireless networks may help you use that ADSL line in different locations; but you will probably not achieve mobility.

For some use cases like the second one you also need to check if such an application violates the contract with your ADSL provider.